# error defining multiple parameters

Tags: verilog, fir

I want to define 19, 16-bit parameter in a way that I can call them like b[0], b[1], b[2], ... 
this is my code:

```
    module optimizedSourceFIRfilter(aclk, s_axis_data_tvalid, s_axis_data_tdata, 
                        s_axis_data_tready, m_axis_data_tvalid, m_axis_data_tdata);

        input aclk, s_axis_data_tvalid;
        input [15:0] s_axis_data_tdata;
        output s_axis_data_tready, m_axis_data_tvalid;
        output [15:0] m_axis_data_tdata;


        parameter signed [15:0] b [18:0];
        b[0] = 26;
        b[1] = 270;
        b[2] = 963;
        b[3] = 2424;
        b[4] = 4869;
        b[5] = 8259;
        b[6] = 12194;
        b[7] = 15948;
        b[8] = 18666;
        b[9] = 19660;
        b[10] = 18666;
        b[11] = 15948;
        b[12] = 12194;
        b[13] = 8259;
        b[14] = 4869;
        b[15] = 2424;
        b[16] = 963;
        b[17] = 270;
        b[18] = 26;
    end module
```

however, this is not working and I got these errors:

```
near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['.
```

and this one

```
vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'b'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

how can I solve that??

**EDIT:**
I also changed `parameter` to `reg`, but I got the same error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only initialize an unpacked array parameter in SystemVerilog.

```
parameter signed [15:0] b [0:18] = {26,270, ... ,26};
```

In Verilog, you would have to pack the array and the select a slice of the parameter. But each slice would be unsigned.

```
   parameter [0:(16*19)-1] b = {16'd26, 16'd270, ... , 16'd26};
```

Then each slice `b[I]` unpacked would be `b[I*16+:16]` packed.